# Autocomplete and dynamic dropdown pulling data too often in Orbeon 4.5

Tags: orbeon

Autocomplete and dynamic dropdown pull data everytime when forms gets changed. Can I narrow down this behaviour, to download data only if a specific field would change?

Cheers

Comment: The autocomplete is supposed to call the service when the control shows for the first time, and every time the value in the control changes or the search URL changes. The dynamic dropdown, when the controls shows for the first time and when the URL changes. There is currently no way to change that. We would like to introduce a notion of datasource to help in the future.

Answer (score 1):

They shouldn't pull data every time form data changes, but only every time the URL changes.

You can use the value of fields in the URL, e.g. passing them as request parameters. In those cases the URL will be reloaded every time the value in those fields changes. But it won't be reloaded if the value in another field, not used on the URL, changes.